# Spock mock returns wrong value

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I have got a strange use case where spock mock is returning the correct value when I do not check for two calls on the mocked class in the 'then:' section, but it is returning 0 when I include two checks in the 'then:' section.
This is the mock:

```
mockDao.readCounter(_, _, _, _, _) >> dbValue
```

and here is the 'then:' section that fails:

```
1 * mockDao.readCounter(_, _, _, _, _)
// updateCounters is called with: sum = dbValue + value
1 * mockDao.updateCounter(namespace, date, key, min, shardID, dbValue + value)
```

In this case, instead of 'dbValue', '0' is returned. But if I comment out either of the two checks, then it passes. So, the following two cases pass:

```
//1 * mockDao.readCounter(_, _, _, _, _)
// updateCounters is called with: sum = dbValue + value
1 * mockDao.updateCounter(namespace, date, key, min, shardID, dbValue + value)

OR

1 * mockDao.readCounter(_, _, _, _, _)
// updateCounters is called with: sum = dbValue + value
//1 * mockDao.updateCounter(namespace, date, key, min, shardID, dbValue + value)
```

Here is the gradle section for spock:

```
// spock
testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7"
compile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.0-groovy-2.4'

// !!! To get none-interface base mocking to work with Spock
compile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '3.2.4'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is expected and documented behavior. If you want to mock and stub on the same mock, you have to do it in one line like

```
1 * mockDao.readCounter(_, _, _, _, _) >> dbValue
```

---

Here the [relevant section](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing):

## Combining Mocking and Stubbing

Mocking and stubbing go hand-in-hand:

```
1 * subscriber.receive("message1") >> "ok"
1 * subscriber.receive("message2") >> "fail"
```

When mocking and stubbing the same method call, they have to happen in the same interaction. In particular, the following Mockito-style splitting of stubbing and mocking into two separate statements will not work:

```
setup:
subscriber.receive("message1") >> "ok"

when:
publisher.send("message1")

then:
1 * subscriber.receive("message1")
```

As explained in [Where to Declare Interactions](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/all_in_one.html#_where_to_declare_interactions), the `receive` call will first get matched against the interaction in the `then:` block. Since that interaction doesn’t specify a response, the default value for the method’s return type (`null` in this case) will be returned. (This is just another facet of Spock’s lenient approach to mocking.). Hence, the interaction in the `setup:` block will never get a chance to match.

**NOTE** | Mocking and stubbing of the same method call has to happen in the same interaction.