# Spock mock won't return correct value

Tags: spock

I have battled with this for several days. This mock will not return `SUCCESS` (true): `1 * realtimeClient.send(_) >> SUCCESS`.
From [question 41841668](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41842105/1082681) I found I needed the `1 *`, which I added without success. I am printing out an intermediate variable of the result of `realtimeClient.send()` and it is always false.

`RealtimeClient` and `QueueClient` are interfaces. I tried coding the `RestfulEmailController` and the Spock test with concrete classes, no change in behavior. I've tried big `Boolean` instead of little `boolean`, no change. The documentation says this should work, and question 41841668 says this should work (although with less complete example code).

```groovy
public static final boolean SUCCESS = true

def "test real time email success"() {
        given:
        RealtimeClient realtimeClient = Mock()
        QueueClient queueClient = Mock()

        1 * realtimeClient.send(_) >> SUCCESS

        RestfulEmailController restfulEmail = new RestfulEmailController(realtimeClient: realtimeClient, queueClient: queueClient)

        RestfulEmailContract email = new RestfulEmail(subject: "some subject")

        when:
        restfulEmail.sendRestfulEmail(email)

        then:
        1 * realtimeClient.send(_)
        0 * queueClient.send(_)
    }
```

and the controller class stripped down to a basic example looks like

```groovy
void sendRestfulEmail(@RequestBody RestfulEmail emailRequest) {
            boolean success = realtimeClient.send(emailRequest)
            System.out.println("success = " + success )
            if (!success ) {
                queueClient.send(emailRequest)
            }
    }
```

nothing I do can make the system print "success = true", and I fail on the expectation for `0 * queueCient.send(_)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Combining Mocking and Stubbing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) in the docs, if you mock something and need to return a value, you must do it at the same time. So if you merge the line `1 * realtimeClient.send(_) >> SUCCESS` from the `given` block into the `then` block, then it returns the value as you'd expect.

```groovy
def "test real time email success"() {
    given:
    RealtimeClient realtimeClient = Mock()
    QueueClient queueClient = Mock()
    RestfulEmailController restfulEmail = new RestfulEmailController(realtimeClient: realtimeClient, queueClient: queueClient)
    RestfulEmailContract email = new RestfulEmail(subject: "some subject")

    when:
    restfulEmail.sendRestfulEmail(email)

    then:
    1 * realtimeClient.send(_) >> SUCCESS
    0 * queueClient.send(_)
}
```

Comment: For others reading this, I want to explicitly say: The mistake the OP made was the redundant `1 * realtimeClient.send(_)` in the `then:` block. It made the previous and correct `1 * realtimeClient.send(_) >> SUCCESS` ineffective, overriding it. Both this answer and the answer to the question the OP referred to explain the correct usage pattern. So does the Spock manual.

Comment: While the first `1 * realtimeClient.send(_) >> SUCCESS` in the `given` block would have worked, it is bad practice to put it there. It is recommended to put the verifying interactions in the then block.

Comment: I fully agree. I just wanted to add a missing piece of explanation to your great answer because even after reading Björn's equally great answer the OP managed to get it wrong.